Displaying Next Element as View Block based on Order ID Field
I have content type in Drupal 10 called "Tutorials". This content type has an integer field named "Order ID" to sort the entries ascending in a normal view.
In the node template for a "Tutorials" I want to display the next "Tutorials" in the sidebar based on the Order ID. I've created a second view block that will be embedded on the Tutorials node page. When I add a filter in the view block for the next Tutorial, I can add the "Order ID", but I can not set the filter to something like "greater than current Order ID". I can't add the Order ID as a relationship since it's not a reference field like it would be when using Taxonomies for example.
Is this doable with normal views or maybe with a module?
I already managed to exclude the current node by using a contextual filter set to "Provide default value" - "Content ID from URL" and the "Exclude" checkbox.

Probably not the answer you want, but I'd recommend doing this as a custom coded block. It's probably quicker/easier than trying to get views to do something it can't readily do

There's a comparison of modules on d.o. If you want to do it code-free you might be able to use Entity Pager (in combination with a view).
